# How to validate elements on PDF loaded in UIWebView in an iOS Native app using XCUITest UI Automation?

Tags: ios, automation, uiwebview, wkwebview, xcuitest

In our application, we have reports which are in `.pdf` format, and we have to validate the report data using XCUITest Automation, we are not able to identify the labels, static texts within the page. can anyone suggest a way to identify elements and validate the report data using XCUITest Framework. we have not found anyway so far! looking for the help. need a way to automate pdf pages within a native app iOS.

so far we have only validating the buttons on the navigation bar on the pdf preview page.

we have to validate the data within the PDF which is loaded in UIWebView.

Comment: It looks complicated. You can take screenshots and do some picture comparison to see if the PDF is generated as expected. But, it may be more valuable to do some unit tests on the PDF generation, isn't it ?